# Sliding Register - Login Forms

Tags: forms

I want to make a sliding Register - Login form on WordPress like this one.
https://codepen.io/zaidik/pen/wvMapoM
Can someone please help me with this?

Edit-Solution: I have found it and its working really good here is the link to the article; https://tootweb.com/creative-sliding-login-register-form/

Comment: Whoa that thing is beautiful. Your question is a really big one and you're unlikely to get any answers because you're not asking anything specific. Implementing this would involve mostly translating and integrating all of the HTML, CSS and javascript there into your Wordpress theme, child theme, or perhaps you could even implement it as a plugin. It's a lot of leg work, so maybe you want to research how Wordpress themes work and have a go at starting that work, and post when you get to a more specific question.

Comment: Yes Thanks, I can do that but I don't know I it will work or not I mean if the user click on login or register it won't login them to the site I think I want to connect it with my website so they can login and register from that page.